# On iOS Safari, using radio button to toggle dom breaks radios/checkboxes

Tags: jquery, ios, safari, radio-button

The following code works fine on all browsers except Safari on iOS (haven't tested android yet).

Simple enough concept. When the user clicks a radio option, I toggle a class to change which additional fields are shown. Works the first time, but after I change it once, all the radio buttons and checkboxes become unclickable.

Here's what the code looks like..
HTML:

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-12 checklist patientOrOther">
  <p>Will this CD be going to you (the patient) or to another facility/clinician?</p>
  <label for="patient"><input type="radio" name="toPatientOrOther" id="patient" value="patient" checked>To the Patient (myself)</label>
  <label for="other"><input type="radio" name="toPatientOrOther" id="other" value="other">To Another Facility/Clinician</label>
</div>
<div class="toPatient">
  <p>Info needed when going to patient</p>
</div>
<div class="toOther hide">
  <p>Info needed when going to another facility/clinician</p>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#patient').bind('change', function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('.toOther').addClass('hide');
    $('.toPatient').removeClass('hide');
  }
});
$('#other').bind('change', function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('.toPatient').addClass('hide');
    $('.toOther').removeClass('hide');
  }
});
```

I've tried using other methods of binding the event, such as `.on('click', function() {});`, `.change()`, etc. I still get the same result on iOS Safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working at https://jsfiddle.net/pc5n3tg0. Tested on iOS 8.1 and note use of jQuery 2.1.3. May be worth editing question to reflect versions, may require more investigation.
Solution uses `on('click')` and sets hide.
Presuming css is

```
.hide {
    display:none;
}
```

JS

```
$('#patient').on('click', function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('.toOther').addClass('hide');
        $('.toPatient').removeClass('hide');
    }
});
$('#other').on('click', function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('.toPatient').addClass('hide');
        $('.toOther').removeClass('hide');
    }
});`
```

Comment: Yeah running jQuery 2.1.3, your css is correct. Maybe having my code inside of a form has something to do with it.. Will try that on your fiddle.